# Como obtener la suma de un array en c#

Tags: c#

tengo un  array que es {1 2 3 4 10 11} y la variable  V=6

la suma del array debe dar el resultado = 31

gracias

Comment: tu pregunta es capciosa?

Comment: sumando esto {1 2 3 4 10 11} quiero obtener como resultado 31

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Has intentado utilizando el metodo [`Sum()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.sum(v=vs.110).aspx) de linq?

```
var numeros = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 10, 11};
var total = numeros.Sum();
Console.WriteLine(total); // 31
```

Answer (score 0):

Existe la funcion Sum() propia del lenguaje

ejemplo de uso:

```
int suma = arr.Sum();
```